# How can i run a task more than once within the grunt initConfig function

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am running a grunt-contrib-clean task at the start of my grunt build to clear out the target directory.  I also want to run another clean task at the end to do some tiding up.

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
    clean: {
        options: { force: true },
        all: {
            //..
        }
    },

    //Other tasks

    clean2: {
        options: { force: true },
        all: {
            //..
        }
    }
});

grunt.registerTask('default', ['']);
grunt.registerTask('build', ['clean', 'clean2']);

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
};
```

How do I call the clean task twice with different arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have already is pretty close. Looking at the documentation for grunt-contrib-clean, it seems you should take a look at their ["long" usage example](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-clean#long-specific-targets-with-per-target-options).

I believe you can do this simply by configuring `clean` as so:

```
clean: {
    target: {
        src: "path/to/target",
        options: { force: true },
        all: {
            //..
        }
    },
    otherFolder: {
        src: "path/to/other/folder",
        options: { force: true },
        all: {
            //..
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can register the task by referencing which `clean` you want:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', ['clean:target', 'clean:otherFolder']);
```

As a side note: I would double check if you really need to use the `force` option. [Per the documentation](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-clean#force): *use with caution*.

Comment: Yeah, ditch the force flag its bad news.